# Android - Is the groupId of sdcard_rw always 1015?

Tags: android, permissions, emulation, sd-card, device

I found out that the group `sdcard_rw` has an id of **1015** on my emulator.

Same on my Nexus One.

Is it fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is fixed, see `android_filesystem_config.h` in android source code:

```
#define AID_SDCARD_RW     1015  /* external storage write access */
```